# Piñata hangs from rope animation

Tags: animation, shape-keys

[image: screencap1]

I want to know if there's a way to have the piñata/hook cling to the rope like in real life.

The rope currently has a shape key that has it drop down like this:

[image: Screencap2]

I have tried adding the piñata as a 'child of' the rope, which does move the piñata/hook with the rope but does nothing when the rope's shape key is set to 1.

would it be easier to animate the piñata manually so it *looks* like it's attached?

Comment: @RobinBetts the vertex parenting works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much you want to animate versus simulate the swing.. but at its simplest, you could (Object Mode) parent the piñata to the line, selecting 'Vertex', that's [Vertex Parenting.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#vertex-parent)